# Django: How to update a class attribute of an invalid form field to display error messages in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: django, django-forms, bootstrap-5

When I use server-side validation in [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/validation/#server-side), I need to add an `.is-invalid` class to the input form field with an error to display it in div with `class="invalid-feedback"`. To update a class attribute of a form field in Django I can do this, as stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances):

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'special'})
        self.fields['comment'].widget.attrs.update(size='40')
```

But I cannot figure out how to add `.is-invalid` to the form field when the form is returned invalid. I have found [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#styling-required-or-erroneous-form-rows) in the docs, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you use crispy forms? It will do it for you automatically: https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know correct way but this way I've done my job

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect("success")
else:
    for field in form.errors:
        form[field].field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' is-invalid'
```

this will add is-invalid class to all invalid fields
**Note:** don't forget to add space `' is-invalid'`

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional css class to all the fields that have errors like this

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for field in self.errors:
            attrs = self[field].field.widget.attrs
            attrs.setdefault("class", "")
            attrs["class"] += " is-invalid"
```